# Can this statement be used as a simile or just as a phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage

Which one can I write?

> 1. As short tempered as I am
> 2. As short tempered as I get

Comment: It's hard to answer questions when you don't even provide a full sentence. Yes, you can say these, but I have no idea if they mean what you think they mean, because you haven't explained what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call either of these similes. Similes are generally figurative, metaphorical, humorous, or they invoke some kind of imagery that is perhaps fantastical.
These are simple comparisons using *as...as*. If I said, "My son is as tall as my daughter," then that's simply an observation that they are the same height. Not a simile.
As to your question, "Which one can I write?" the answer is either; they are not exactly the same, but close. More context is needed.

Answer (score 0):

A simile is a comparison between two similar things, in order to convey the known characteristics of one thing onto the other.

> He was as strong as an ox.
>
> Her singing was like nails on a chalkboard.

And so on. Your examples are simple descriptions of character, and not similes.  If you wanted to make a simile, you would say something like these:

> As short-tempered as a spoiled house cat.
>
> As short-tempered as a rattlesnake.

Otherwise, both are fine expressions, with only subtle differences in nuance between "am" and "get".  One implies this is how you are *now*, and the other implies that you are not currently short-tempered, but it's something you become quickly.